# Angular - passing parameters to child component - good practice

Tags: angular

I wonder what the best (clean) way is to pass parameters to a child component and call some method.
In my project I do this with a couple of ways.

Let’s say we have `alert.component` with `show` method. Where promise is fulfilled we want to call it (in `app.component`).

**1.**  I create the `alert` selector in the `app.component` template. In the `app.component.ts` I create the `@ViewChild alert` and call `alert.show(params)`. Eventually I create `ngIf` in the template to display an alert at the right time.

*app.component.ts*

```
@ViewChild(AlertComponent)
private alertComponent: AlertComponent;

[...]

alertComponent.show(params);
```

*app.component.html*

```
<alert *ngIf(condition)></alert>
```

**2.**  I create the `alert` selector in the `app.component` template and there I pass some params: `alert([params]="params")`. I don’t create any `@ViewChild` in `app.component.ts` but an `@Input()` in the`alert.component.ts`. The `show` method is called in the`ngOnChanges()`.

*alert.component.ts*

```
@Input() params: any;
@Input() condition: boolean;

[...]

OnChanges() {
 if (condition)
  this.show(params);
}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<alert [condition]="condition", [params]="params"></alert>
```

**Which way would you choose?**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Typically, UI components like alert boxes are managed by a service that you inject inside the component, NOT by the parent component. The service lets you talk to the alert component from EVERYWHERE in your  app; you can also use the service to pass data to the component. This is more reusable / less coupled than having the parent component call methods on its child and pass data via inputs.

Comment: `alert.component` is just an example. Apparently wrongly chosen. I ask about communication between components in general.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's hard to advise on best practices in general. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, one technique might be better than the other.

Comment: I fail to understand the point of calling show() on the alert component: if you change the condition of the ngIf to true, the alert component appears. If you change it back to false, it disappears. All you need is to change a boolean. No need to call show().

Comment: Using `@Input` and `@Output` provide a clean way to define an outward API for a particular component. This outward API is then available to reuse the component anywhere it is needed. Consider only using ViewChild if you need access to an element in the view that you don't "own". For example, if you want to get access to a form element displayed in a view to check its dirty or valid state. Or if you need to pass it to another third party component, such as for google maps.